# Weighted median in java

Tags: java, algorithm, average

I'm trying to program a program to compute Weighted Median, but I have a small problem I couldn't solve.
to find the Weighted Median, you have to divide each weight by the sum then compare it with 0.5 if greater means the Weighted Median found then return the corresponding x value.
here an example:

```
x = [3,4,6,10]
w = [1,2,3,5]
1/11 > 1/2 ? no
1/11+ 2/11 > 1/2 ? no
1/11+ 2/11 + 3/11 > 1/2 ? yes
```

then return the 6 as it's the corresponding for 3

here's my attempt:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = new int[] {3,4,6,10};
    int[] w = new int[] {1,2,3,5};
    int sum = Arrays.stream(w).sum();//11

    if ((w[0]/sum)>0.5){
        System.out.print("The weighted meadin is " + x[0]);
    }
    else if ((w[0]/sum)+(w[1]/sum)>0.5){
        System.out.print("The weighted meadin is " + x[1]);
    }
    else if ((w[0]/sum)+(w[1]/sum)+(w[2]/sum)>0.5){
        System.out.print("The weighted meadin is " + x[2]);
    }
    else if ((w[0]/sum)+(w[1]/sum)+(w[2]/sum)+(w[3]/sum)>0.5){
        System.out.print("The weighted meadin is " + x[3]);
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("The weighted meadin not found");
    }
}
```

this always returns last else statement.

Comment: You're using an int-division in w[0]/sum and the like, which will always be zero. Switch to float or double, for a start.

Comment: thanks!! I knew it was a silly mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in the `w` array and the `sum` variable are all `int`s, so when performing a `/` operation you're in fact performing [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers) - i.e., you're keeping only the "whole" part of the division, which is always `0` in this case.

Defining one of the operands as a `double` will make Java use floating point division, and solve your problem. E.g.:

```
double sum = Arrays.stream(w).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Each division operation you use is integer division, since both operands are integers.

Try making it a floating point division.
One way is to rewrite each `w[0] / sum` and the like into `w[0] * 1.0 / sum`, for example.
Another is to just declare the `sum` variable as `double`.